# Select all non-null column names per row in spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  Y  |null |  Y  |null |
|null |  N  |  N  |null |
|  N  |  Y  |null |  N  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to add a new column that is a concatenation of the names of all non-null columns for each row.

So, for the example above, it would add a new column

```
+--------+
|non-null|
+--------+
| A, C   |
| B, C   |
| A, B, D|
+--------+
```

Is there any easy way to do this? I've tried looking for an anti-coalesce, something that would, if not null, use the supplied name. For example, if there was an anti-coalesce:

```
df.withColumn("non-null", antiCoalesce("A", "A,") + antiCoalesce("B", "B,") + antiCoalesce("C", "C,") + antiCoalesce("D", "D"))
```

Alas, there is no such function, but it demonstrates what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Spark 2.4+, you can do something like this:

```
val nonNullColsExpr = df.columns.map(c => when(col(c).isNotNull, lit(c)))

df.withColumn("non_null", array(nonNullColsExpr:_*))
  .withColumn("non_null", expr("array_join(non_null, ',')"))
  .show()

//+----+----+----+----+--------+
//|   A|   B|   C|   D|non_null|
//+----+----+----+----+--------+
//|   Y|null|   Y|null|     A,C|
//|null|   N|   N|null|     B,C|
//|   N|   Y|null|   N|   A,B,D|
//+----+----+----+----+--------+
```

First, we create an array column that contains column names that satisfy the condition `isNotNull` and those that do not satisfy will be nulled. And then join the elements with [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) using `,` delimiter (`array_join` filters the null values when joining the elements).

Comment: Perfect. Wow, that is really thinking outside the box. Awesome! :D

Comment: Sorry for asking but I've been struggling for all day... How can I convert this expression into `pyspark`?

Comment: @GuidoCioni in Pyspark, you can do something like this: `non_null_cols = [when(col(c).isNotNull, lit(c)) for c in df.columns]` then use it : `df.withColumn("non_null", array(*non_null_cols))`. The rest remains the same as in Scala.

Comment: I was able to use it like this `ds
        .withColumn("missing_L", F.array(*[F.when(F.isnull(c), F.lit(c)) for c in ds.columns]))
        .withColumn("missing_L", F.expr("array_join(missing_L, ', ')"))
        .withColumn("missing_L", F.regexp_replace(F.col("missing_L"), "on object", ""))
        .select("msn", "missing_L")`

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach? You can `concat_ws` with new columns which are containing the name of column when it is not null.

```
val df = Seq(("Y", null, "Y", null),
             (null, "N", "N", null),
             ("N", "Y", null, "N")).toDF("A", "B", "C", "D")

val columns = df.columns
columns.foldLeft(df) {(df, name) => df.withColumn(name + "2", when(!col(name).isNull, lit(name)))}
  .withColumn("non-null", concat_ws(",", columns.map(name => col(name + "2")): _*))
  .drop(columns.map(name => name + "2"): _*)
  .show(false)
```

Then,

```
+----+----+----+----+--------+
|A   |B   |C   |D   |non-null|
+----+----+----+----+--------+
|Y   |null|Y   |null|A,C     |
|null|N   |N   |null|B,C     |
|N   |Y   |null|N   |A,B,D   |
+----+----+----+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can express this using `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(',', 
                 (case when A is not null then 'A' end),
                 (case when B is not null then 'B' end),
                 (case when C is not null then 'C' end),
                 (case when D is not null then 'D' end)
                )
```

Comment: That does work, but it is dreadfully slow. Is there a more efficient way of doing that?

Comment: @GeoffreySaunders . . . I have no idea why this would be "dreadfully slow".  It is just doing relatively simple computations on each row.  I can't actually think of anything much faster.

Comment: I had an implementation that did something like this, and it really takes a long time, so I didn't consider it. I should have posted that as a solution I tried doing when I wrote up the question. I can post what I had in the question above, but it's almost exactly what you posted here.